# Variável muda valor quando chama função

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, lista, variáveis

Criei uma variável `v`, que recebe `n` números aleatórios. quando crio outra variável chamando uma função e passando `v` por parâmetro, o `v` muda.

```
n = int(input("Entre com o tamanho de vetor: "))
v = [0]*n
for i in range(0,n):
    v[i] = randint(0,100)
print(v)


bS=bubbleSort(v)
print(bS)
cS=countingSort(v)
print(cS)
iS=insertionSort(v)
print(iS)
mS=mergeSort(v)
print(mS)
qS=quickSort(v,0,n-1)
print(qS)
sS=selectionSort(v)
print(sS)

print(v)
```

Comment: Só muda porque uma (ou mais) dessas funções que você chamou está alterando a variável. Não deveria alterar o valor?

Comment: Todas as funções estão alterando o valor? Coloca o código de alguma destas que estão mudando o valor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O tipo de dado que está usando é chamado de tipo por referência, por isso você não tem o objeto de forma direta, você tem uma indireção para o objeto. A variável possui uma referência para para o objeto e não tem esses valores que está colocando nele de forma direta (não vou entrar em detalhes específicos como Python lida com isto que não vem ao caso aqui).

Quando chama a função passando essa lista como argumento está passando essa referência e não está passando o objeto em si. Portanto tudo o que for feito dentro da função fará no objeto apontado pela referência, então uma mudança lá se reflete na variável que foi usada como argumento porque foi mudado um objeto único.

Para passar o objeto ele teria que ser copiado por completo e em geral não é o que deseja fazer. A não ser neste caso, pelo descrito na pergunta não quer que o objeto seja mudado, por isso precisa copiá-lo manualmente para obter o resultado desejado.

Uma forma de copiar a lista seria assim:

```
bS = v[:]
bS = bubbleSort(v)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/SliceCopy.py).

Pode fazer isso quantas vezes quiser, cada uma será uma cópia diferente e cada variável nova terá uma referência para um objeto diferente. A função não mudará o comportamento, ela vai mudar seu objeto, mas agora cada um deles é independente do outro, você não aponta mais para o mesmo objeto sempre.

Você nem precisa criar mais variáveis do que já criou, apenas tem que fazer isto antes, realizando a cópia.

Só tenha claro que a cópia é uma operação custosa se a lista for muito grande, o que nem é o caso mais comum do exemplo (será se colocar um `n` muito grande, mas se só faz isso não será um problema tão grande), mas é bom saber pra não abusar disto.

A única forma disto não acontecer é se as funções fizerem a cópia internamente, o que explicaria ter um retorno. Se foi você que fez essas funções o problema pode estar aí, não está fazendo a cópia lá dentro. Se fizer a cópia seria bom documentar isso porque ela será uma função bem "cara", fazer uma cópia **e** uma classificação, e nem sempre é óbvio que está fazendo isso, ser óbvio é importante. Aí não precisaria fazer a cópia fora. Se não fizer esta cópia então não tem porque retornar nada.